# sourcing and displaying R source code in R Markdown without executing

Tags: r, markdown

I am writing a book in R Markdown. I saved a lot of code in separate .R files. For didactical purpose I need to show the whole file's contents without actually running it.

e.g., I would like that

```
r my_r_chunk
source("./code/mycodefile.R")
```

```

would be rendered displaying the whole content of `mycodefile.R` without actually executing it.

Comment: do you just want `readLines("./code/mycodefile.R")` or maybe `cat(readLines("./code/mycodefile.R"), sep="\n")`

Answer (score -1):

Check out `?knitr::read_chunk`

First, assign a label to the script using the syntax `## ---- your_label ----` by placing it in the first line of the script which is called `foo.R`

**foo.r**

```
## ---- your_label ----

print("Hello World")
1:10
```

After assigning the script a label, you can then `read_chunk` the script in an uncached chunk. Finally you reference the contents in a subsequent (cached) chunk using the `eval = FALSE` chunk option.

**your_Rmd_file.Rmd**

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r cache=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
read_chunk('foo.R')
```

```{r your_label, cache = TRUE, eval=FALSE}

```
````